VS Code autocomplete for discord.js module exports
I code discord bot in VS Code. I liked it but sometimes its too hard becasuse autocomplete doesn't work. I have main file and then folder with all commands.
In main file i have something like this:
bot.commands.get('help').execute(message) in messageCreate event.
Then i have in help.js:
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'bots commands',
    execute(message){
     code...
    }
}

In help.js file autocomplete doesn't work, because i think VS Code doesn't know what it is.
I can it specify with @param (code below) but it's quite complicated if I were to specify all these parameters. For example if i use buttons and collectors and much more.
/**
* 
* @param {Message} message
*/

I downloaded Webstorm from Jetbrains and it can autocomplete even in files.
Is there any plugin for VS Code or how i can fix it?

Javascript is an untyped language, you'll eventually lose the type reference for variables if you do not use JSDOCs. If typings/type safety is a concern, consider using TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/

You can create a generic command type using JSDoc typedefs in a separate types file that can be applied to all command files:
// types.js

/**
 * @typedef Command
 * @property {string} name - Name of the command
 * @property {string} description - Command description
 * @property {CommandExecute} execute - Command execution
 */

/**
 * @callback CommandExecute
 * @param {import("discord.js").Message} message - Interaction message
 */

module.exports = {};

Do note that you may need to specify an empty object as the module.exports of the types file so that VSCode registers it as a file that can be imported.
From there, you can simply use a single line to add types instead of specifying JSDoc for every command:
/** @type {import("./types.js").Command} */
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "bot command",
    execute(message) {
        // message should now be typed as a Discord.js Message
    }
}

